# Can you think of SQL JOINs as loops?

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to understand SQL JOINs and I'm wondering whether it makes sense to think of them as loops.

Does this pseudo code express what the database is doing?

```
table leftTable
    name: text
    id: integer

table rightTable
    name: text
    id: integer

out "inner join:"
each leftTable as l
    each rightTable as r
        if l.id = r.id
            out "record:"
            out l.name
            out r.name

out "left outer join:"
each leftTable as l
    out "record:"
    out l.name
    each rightTable as r
        if l.id = r.id
            out r.name

out "right outer join:"
each rightTable as r
    out "record:"
    each leftTable as l
        if l.id = r.id
            out l.name
    out r.name

out "full outer join:"
each leftTable as l
    each rightTable as r
        out "record:"
        out l.name
        out r.name
```

Assume that I know nothing about relational algebra! But you've surely already guessed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  A SQL join describes how two tables (or views or subqueries or CTEs or whatever) are combined in a query to produce results.

One algorithm for implementing joins is definitely the nested loop algorithm, which is basically what you describe.

So, it is a valid way of *thinking* about joins.  However, the SQL optimizer is free to choose whatever algorithm it wants for `JOIN`s.  And, there are actually many algorithms, depending on factors such as:

- The presence or absence of indexes.
- The type of join.
- The sizes and relative sizes of the tables.
- The availability of multiple processors and other resources.
- The statistics about the columns used in the joins.
- And no doubt more!

So, what actually runs may have nothing to do with looping.  But you can rest assured that it produces the same result -- but probably faster.

Comment: Does that mean the descriptive nature of SQL allows for more optimizations by a compiler whereas my procedural example can only be optimized in a limited number of ways by a compiler?

Comment: @ArminRepsold . . . That is a reasonable description of the difference.  Procedural languages do not have the flexibility to "change the implementation".

Answer (score 0):

For the table leftTable, I'd define one more attribute, "rightID". rightID would be the FK (Foreign Key) in the leftTable column, so you could have the relationship between these 2 columns. It doesn't make sense to create JOINs with PKs (Primary Keys). I know it doesn't answer your question about the pseudo-code, but I think it was valid to point it out.

Comment: I understand that, yes. My fictitious database has no keys to simplify the example.